# What is a software which can draw by just typing?

Tags: drawing

About twenty years ago, I came into contact with a software which can draw (e.g. a line) by typing on it (e.g. typing some code, then push "ENTER" (I am not sure about this part), a line will appear on the screen). I think there was no way to choose the color of the drawn line.

Now I want to look at this software again, but I did not remember the software name. Do anyone on this site have any idea what this software is?

To rephrase, I am asking for a software that  draw (e.g. a possibly one-colored line) by typing on it (e.g. typing some code, then push "ENTER" (I am not sure about this part), a line will appear on the screen).

PS. Please inform me if the you think that this is not an appropriate question to ask here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and rewrite it so that it asks for "software to do X", otherwise [it is off topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic). [Read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) for more information.

Comment: is `gs` with postscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)) programming language.

The simple Logo drawing commands move the "turtle" (drawing pen) forward and backward and turn it right or left. The commands and their abbreviations are given below:

> ```
> fd forward 
> bk backward 
> rt right 
> lt left 
> cs clearscreen
> ```

The commands

```
     fd 60 rt 120 fd 60 rt 120 fd 60 rt 120
```

cause the turtle to draw a triangle, as you can see by trying them out - there is a free Logo in the browser site at http://logo.twentygototen.org/

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! You might want to mention that a similar capability resides in Python with the turtle graphics library: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle

Comment: You just did! Thanks for that :-) takes me back to about 1980 and an Apple ... was it a Lisa?